# catalog for spatial plan objects GIS

Tags: documentation

I want to make plan of building apartments. To make it I have to know what layers I need have and what attributes they must have (for example,communications).
Maybe somebody knows is there something like it exists? Or what can help me to do it.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "plan of building apartments," do you mean a blueprint for each floor? Or do you mean the layout of an apartment complex? The requirements, what they 'must' have, will vary depending on the country/state/province you are in. If you live in the U.S., your local county planning/zoning department may have information to help you in the right direction (this is an example: http://eservice.pwcgov.org/ebuildingdevelopmentforms/forms/newstructuresadditionschecklist.pdf).

I believe ArcGIS CityEngine may have what you need, though there may be licensing restrictions. I don't believe it is included with standard ArcGIS. ArcGIS Pro may also have the capabilities you are looking for. This site may be helpful: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/3d/

Comment: I need both of the options - a plan for each floor plan and residential complex.
The information you have given is useful, but if you can give me something more detailed, I will be grateful.

Comment: I edited my comment. Sorry I can't be more detailed! This is not my domain. Unless the plans for floors and the complex overall need to be integrated with other GIS data, you may want to look for other architectural software (e.g. AutoCAD's Building Design suite).